# Can you say "She has been slandering me"

Tags: grammar

This sentence sounds a bit odd to me; however I believe it's grammatically correct. Could you please corroborate for me.
Sentence: 
"She has been slandering me/her/him"

Comment: Try googling it and see if anyone (in a reputable source, or at least one you personally trust on these matters) has put it this way.

Answer (score 2):

"**[To slander](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slander)**" is the verb. As a transitive verb, it takes an object (in this case, "*me*"). "has been slandering" is the correct formation of the present perfect progressive tense for the third person ("*she*").

So: Yes, it is correct.